# pass parameter by link_to ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have this line of code:

```
<%= link_to "Add to cart", :controller => "car", :action => "add_to_cart", :car => car %>
```

when im in the add_to_cart method...how can i call the :car please?

```
@car = Car.new(params[:car])
```

That doesn't work because it says that I'm trying to stringify it.

I don't understand what's wrong; because I used this to create new users and it worked fine.

By the way, car is my car object.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= link_to "Add to cart", {:controller => "car", :action => "add_to_cart", :car => car.id }%>
```

and then in your controller

```
@car = Car.find(params[:car])
```

which, will find in your 'cars' table  (as with rails pluralization) in your DB a car with id == to car.id

Comment: But what if the parameter depends on, let's say, the value of an input, which may be dynamic in nature?

Answer (score 80):

The above did not work for me but **this** did

`<%= link_to "text_to_show_in_url", action_controller_path(:gender => "male", :param2=> "something_else") %>`

Answer (score 7):

Maybe try this:

```
<%= link_to "Add to cart", 
            :controller => "car", 
            :action => "add_to_cart", 
            :car => car.attributes %>
```

But I'd really like to see where the car object is getting setup for this page (i.e., the rest of the view).

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to pass the `car` object as a parameter, try just passing `car.id`.  What do you get when you `inspect(params)` after clicking "Add to cart"?

Comment: the problem with that is that I don't have these cars saved anywhere since I'm scraping the informatin from the web and am not storing them anywhere..thus the id is non-existent as yet and apart from that would be useless :/

Comment: Once again, what do you get when you inspect(params)?

Comment: params[:product].inspect came back empty ""

Comment: if you don't have an 'id' what do you expect to become a parameter?