# How to assign a variable as a route parameter in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a static page that has several links.  These links route to the pro_show action in my Posts controller.

```
 def pro_show
   @posts = Post.where(:code => @code)
 end
```

I want to pass in the value of :code through my routes. :code is a string.
Right now my routes look like the below route.  How do I assign a string value to @code ?  I DO NOT need to change the :code of any Post.  I need to use the @code variable to sort my Post records as you can see in my action.

This is what I am doing right now=>

```
<td><%= link_to "This Post", pro_show_path(@code => 87889) %></td>
```

Am I doing this correctly?  Does the value of @code need to be in quotes? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass parameter by link\_to ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898737/pass-parameter-by-link-to-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work

```
<td><%= link_to "This Post", pro_show_path(:code => 87889) %></td>
```

And in the controller

```
def pro_show
  @posts = Post.where(:code => params[:code])
end
```