# Vague error: undefined method `encoding' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I visit my procedure_list view I get this error: undefined method `encoding' for nil:NilClass

Apparently the source of the error is on line 12, which is the first link_to method:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>List of Procedures</th>

  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to "Service 1", pro_show_path(@code => 99281) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Service 2", pro_show_path(@code => 99282) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Service 3", pro_show_path(@code => 99283) %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my controller action:

```
def pro_show
  @procedures = Procedure.where(:code => @code)
end
```

Everything looks okay to me..not sure what I did wrong..

Comment: Your stack trace will point you to the exact place where the error occurs - please include it.

Comment: You've asked the [same question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763008/how-to-assign-a-variable-as-a-route-parameter-in-rails)?

Comment: I thought the answer to that question worked, but now it is throwing an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It should be

```
<td><%= link_to "Service 1", pro_show_path(code: 99281) %></td>
```

But it still looks strange

`@code` looks like undefined variable

```
@procedures = Procedure.where(:code => @code)
```

Did you set `@code` from `params[:code]`?

Comment: It gets defined in the link_to doesn't it?

Comment: Both places where I set @code are included in the question,  The link_to works now using code: 99281, but throws an uninitialized constant error when clicked.