# pass params to controller method via link_to rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to pass a params from a text_field_tag to my controller but it doesnt get passed via link_to

```
      <div class="row" id="page-search">
        <%= hidden_field_tag :page, params[:page], class: 'form-control', value: '1'%>
        <%= text_field_tag :page, params[:page], class: 'form-control', id: 'show-page'%>
        <%= link_to 'Go', currencies_path, :remote => true, method: :get, class: "btn btn-default", id: "show-button" %>
      </div>
```

controller method

```
      def index
        @currencies = Currency.all.page(params[:page]).per(10)
      end
```

It should call this method which it does but it doesnt pass the params[:page]. Any clue as to how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Based on suggestions, i did this but i am still facing the same issue as it doesnt pass the params

```
       <%= form_tag currencies_path, :method => :get do -%>
          <%= text_field_tag :page, params[:page], class: 'form-control', id: 'show-page'%>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :page, params[:page], class: 'form-control', value: '1'%>
          <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass parameter by link\_to ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898737/pass-parameter-by-link-to-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @Bijendra its a different question. urs is based on passing object data. mine is based on pasing text_field_tag input

Answer (score 1):

Links are self-contained:  they only care about what is in their own arguments.

If you want to submit params from fields on the page, then you need to wrap those fields in a **form** and submit the form.

If you want to put that data into the link then you can change the link_to thus:

```
    <%= link_to 'Go', currencies_path(page => 1), :remote => true, method: :get, class: "btn btn-default", id: "show-button" %>
```

Comment: i want to be based on text_field_tag input so the value of page cannot be static as u hv put it in. is there anyway to do it? if i do page => params[:page] will tht work

Comment: Change it to a form.

Comment: i edited and changed to a form but still it doesnt submit

Comment: Remember it's a remote form, so it won't *do* anything when you submit. You should post your log to show what's happening

Comment: Have you replaced the link with a submit button?

Answer (score 1):

This will send the value that is input as part of the text field tag.

```
<%= form_tag currencies_path, :method => :get do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :page, nil, class: 'form-control', id: 'show-page'%>
      <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
<% end %>
```

I am not sure why you set params[:page] as a value for text-field. Or am i missing something here?

In case you want to use the params[:page], set it to a variable in the action,

```
@page_number = params[:page]
```

The html should be changed to,

```
<%= text_field_tag :page, @page_number, class: 'form-control', id: 'show-page'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't advocate submitting the same value for both `hidden` and `text` fields:

```
<%= form_tag currencies_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :page, params[:page], class: 'form-control', id: 'show-page'
   <%= submit_tag "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

You must remember, your current form uses `remote: true`, which is the ajax wrapper for [`Rails UJS`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for). Thus, if you want to check what happens, you need to make sure you've removed `remote: true` from the form declaration.

--

If you wanted to set the value statically (IE the user cannot change), you'll want to look at [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to), as this can pass `params` through a `hidden` field:

```
<%= button_to "Go", currencies_path, method: :get, params: { page: "1" } %>
```

The problem with this is that you cannot change the page in the view (the value you assign in the params hash will be static).

Comment: A remote form will still submit, it will just do it via an ajax call.  It looks prettty much the same in the log, except for the response.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. The OP said that "nothing was happening" / "won't submit" - was just alluding to the fact that remote will make it appear that nothing would appear unless the response was caught.

Comment: ah i see.  :)  OP: watch your log file.

Comment: ur suggestions were right, my implementation was wrong, it works now