# link_to with controller name, action, method and additional arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a `link_to` with the name of the controller, action and also pass additional arguments. The method type is `post`
Currently, I have:

```
<%= link_to "Name", {controller: "users", action: "custom"}, method: "post" %>
```

How do I pass in additional arguments to the above? If it's not possible to do this with a `link_to`, what are my other options?

Comment: Here is a fantastic post on this, i definitely have used this in the past. Although passing data through a link_to is not ideal, it works well enouugh.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898737/pass-parameter-by-link-to-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

you can pass more parameters inside the {}

```
<%= link_to "Name", {controller: "users", action: "custom", first_parameter:"foo", second_parameter:"bar"}, method: "post" %>
```

Comment: I tried that. But the params are being included in the URL. Is there a way I can avoid that? I don't need to necessarily use a link_to

Comment: oh, you mean pass those parameters like there are inputs in a flied... that can not be done, at least not in a simple way like that. you need to create a form for that or make an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do POST then you should be using [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to), with the default POST behavior (though, you don't have to):

```
<%= button_to "Name", { controller: "users", action: "custom", param1: "param1", param2: "param2" } %>
```

Comment: I tried that, and the parameters still get included in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [hidden_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag)