# get css class of clicked link in next action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a link

> <%= link_to 'edit', action: :edit_employee, controller: :admin, {:class => 'dialog'} %>

And in the edit_employee action i want to say something like:

> if :class = 'dialog' then render layout: false end

Is it possible to get that HTML class from the action after clicked without sending a parameter?

Comment: Without sending a parameter? No.

Comment: just pass an extra param duplicating your class like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898737/pass-parameter-by-link-to-ruby-on-rails

Comment: The OP says "without sending a parameter"...

Comment: dohhh, but why ...

Comment: Maybe he means by not sending a param: not sending a form. He may not know he can just add the param to a link_to. Otherwise creating a specific action for each value of class. But not very dry.

Comment: Without sending parameters it is not possible. Please share your exact requirement. Are you trying to open dialog box ? If yes than you add `remote: true` and check for `xhr?` if no than you will have to share what you are trying to achieve

Comment: That's what i thought... The reason why I didn't want a param was because If someone copies the link, i want the layout to show. Yes it is a dialog when clicked

Comment: @DevonQuick i have given you an alternative way to do this, let me know if its useful for you . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative way to do this to send a `hidden_field` but with this you would need to use `form`

for example: -

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'admin', :action => 'edit_employee') do  %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'is_dialog', 'true'  %>
  <!--you can edit this button using css to look it like `link_to` -->
  <% content_tag :button :type => :submit, :class => :your_class do %>
     Edit
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

at controller you can do this: -

```
def edit_employee
  if params[:is_dialog] == 'true'
   #render layout: false
  else
   #your code...
  end
end
```

hope its clear for you,this is just an alternative way, otherwise you can do is using ajax request in which whatever you will send will not visible in url,